# I want to change the title of jframe. i want to use the value set from jMenu2

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
public class HomeBrowse extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    /**
     * Creates new form HomeBrowse
     */
    public HomeBrowse() {
        initComponents();
        this.setSize(743, 528);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        new NetInfo().say();
    }


public class NetInfo {

     public void say() {
       try {
       java.net.InetAddress i = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
       System.out.println(i.getHostName()); 
       jMenu2.setText(i.getHostName());
       }
       catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
     }
    }

public void Title() {

}
```

Comment: Why not have the say method return the host name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution proposed by @MadProgrammer as code

```
public class HomeBrowse extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    /**
     * Creates new form HomeBrowse
     */
    public HomeBrowse() {
        initComponents();
        this.setSize(743, 528);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        setTitle(new NetInfo().say());
    }
}

public class NetInfo {

     public String say() {
       try {
           java.net.InetAddress i = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
           System.out.println(i.getHostName()); 
           jMenu2.setText(i.getHostName());
           return i.getHostName();
       }
       catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice to help you. Could you check it as the best answer?